# Orchard cms Cache Module returning double page

Tags: caching, memcached, orchardcms

I have a working instance of [Orchard Cms](http://www.orchardproject.net/) installed on [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/)

I've installed the [Cache Module](http://orchardcache.codeplex.com/) as well as [memcached module](https://github.com/sebastienros/Contrib.Cache.Memcached), and configured it for use on AppHarbor

But when I enable the cache and put a duration of 3600 the page loads twice.

Rather it loads once but the html is repeated twice

you can see this [here](http://riders-test.apphb.com/) ... (for the next 24 hrs!)

I'm currently looking at the cache source code. But not sure where to start with this.

( Orchard 1.6 )

Comment: No idea what could be causing that: me and my customers are using cache on many sites (including memcached) without such issues. I'm sending this to Sébastien in case he has an idea.

Comment: Does it repro if you disable the memcached module ?

Comment: Can you add the debug information in the rendered page, it's a setting in the options of the cache module.

Comment: I've disabled Memcached module and ticked the debug option on cache settings, I'm not seeing any debug output, and stil getting the duplicate page

Comment: Can you contact me on Skype ? firstnamelastname

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I'm having the same issues. I'm also using the Image Resizer http module.

Comment: I removed the S3 reader module, didn't find a better resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was to do with using the [image resizer](http://imageresizing.net/) s3 reader module, with the caching module, I didn't manage to fix this, so removed the image resizer module